# How to get a good file upload button in bootstrap 4 laravel 5?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5, bootstrap-4

I want to get a file upload input like in the below example

https://www.codeply.com/go/SkIJQ5LqKp/bootstrap-4-file-input

```
<input type="file" id="dp_file_input" name="demo" />
```

This outputs a very bad look and therefore i want to have the one that is shown in the link.

Even after copying the code as it is, its not displaying anything at all. 
Bootstrap and all other things are working properly only problem is that the file input is not displaying.

```css
#customFile .custom-file-control:lang(en)::after {
  content: "Select file...";
}

#customFile .custom-file-control:lang(en)::before {
  content: "Click me";
}

/*when a value is selected, this class removes the content */
.custom-file-control.selected:lang(en)::after {
  content: "" !important;
}

.custom-file {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.custom-file-control {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<br>
<div class="container">
    This is not working
    <label class="custom-file" id="customFile">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="exampleInputFile" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
        <span class="custom-file-control form-control-file"></span>
    </label>
    
    <input type="file" id="dp_file_input" name="demo" />
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: What have you tried? Show your code.

Comment: Please read input group bootstrap 4 documentation

Comment: i have added the sample code. You can see its not working even after including bootstrap 4 CDN

Comment: The code you've provided *does* work when Bootstraps CSS and JS are loading correctly. I suspect there is an error in your above CSS (perhaps the `integrity` is wrong?)  Also note that 4.0.0-beta.3 has an error with this component: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/25112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the basic code you need to get it to work in Bootstrap 4:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <label class="custom-file border">
                    <input type="file" id="inputGroupFile02" class="custom-file-input" required>
                    <span class="custom-file-control pr-3" style="white-space: nowrap;">Select file... </span>
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupFile02">Click Me</span>
                    </div>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: why is it showing two upload buttons that are separated and they are not clickable

Comment: i noticed that after selecting the file the "select file" text does not change to filename